# VBA to create password protected file

Tags: excel, vba

With the below coding, I am able to create a copy of password protected file. But I also want to put the password in newly created file.
How can I add password while creating new excel workbook.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, Password:="yourpassword", UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws1 = Worksheets("OJT Plan")
ws1.Activate
filen = TextBox3.Text & "_" & TextBox59 & "_" & VBA.Format(Now, "MMddyyyyhmmss AM/PM ")
ws1.SaveAs Sheet1.Range("V3").Value & filen & ".xlsx"
Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Details"
Set ws13 = Worksheets("Details")
```

Comment: Having a look at the Microsoft References [Workbook.SaveAs Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) should help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) you will see there are two password arguments for the `SaveAs` command

```
ws1.SaveAs FileName:=Sheet1.Range("V3").Value & filen & ".xlsx", _
           Password:="yourpassword", _                                
           WriteResPassword:="yourreadonlypassword"
```

The difference in these two password arguments is explained in the docs:

> **`Password`**: A case-sensitive string (no more than 15 characters) that indicates the protection password to be given to the file.
>
> **`WriteResPassword`**: A string that indicates the write-reservation password for this file. If a file is saved with the password and the password isn't supplied when the file is opened, the file is opened as read-only.